# Angular ng serve stop working on 10%. I have changed --port 443 but not working

Tags: angular

Angular ng serve stop working on 10%. I have changed --port 443 but not working. I need a help, why this is not working and what should i do.

Dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.1.14",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "7.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^3.0.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.5.1",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^1.0.16",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-editor-n": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-linkifyjs": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "yarn": "1.12.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.0.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^7.3.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "10.12.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your might be running the ng serve method from the wrong path

As seen in the image your current path is set inside the dist folder which is wrong

Do a `cd ..` and come to the front-end folder and then do
`ng serve`

Comment: Sir, angular project is in dist folder, its not build, its is code with node_modules. Its starts serving but stopped on 10%.